# Apply certain condition or validation to restrict operation in Laravel Models

Tags: php, laravel-5

[image]

This is a `category` table I am using in my project using Laravel.
I have checks applied in the view files, for the `category` `parent` selection dropdown, so that the `category` itself and it's `child's` will not appear in the dropdown.

But form input fields value can be easily overridden using dev console.

Is there a way in models so that if `parent id` is equal to the `category id` itself or `parent id` is the `child` of current `category` then it will stop execution.

I have recently started laravel, a month ago, and still learning and building, so help here will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by overriding the update method in model -

Controller update method -

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
            $this->validate($request,
                            ['name' => 'required',]);

            $data = [];

            $data = ['name'   => Input::get('name'),
                     'parent' => !empty(Input::get('parent')) ? Posts_categories::find(Input::get('parent'))->id : NULL,];

            $category = Posts_categories::find($id);

            if(is_null($category))
            {
                Session::flash('flash-message', 'Category type with the given id does not exist.');
                Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-warning');

                return redirect()->route('admin.post.category.index');
            }

            if($category->update($data)) {
                Session::flash('flash-message', 'Category succesfully updated.');
                Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-success');
            }

            return redirect()->route('admin.post.category.index');
        }
```

Model update method -

```
public function update(array $attributes = [], array $options = [])
        {
            $parent = SELF::find($attributes['parent']);

            if($this->id == $parent->id || $this->id == $parent->parent)
            {
                Session::flash('flash-message', 'Invalid parent selection for category.');
                Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-warning');
                return 0;
            }

            return parent::update($attributes, $options); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
        }
```

Comment: You have added the validation in the controller part. But i need to added  that validation in validation function then how can it possible?